# Why two phase locking requires second phase not able to acquire lock for another object?

Tags: database-theory

I wonder why two phase locking is designed in a way that as long as you release **a** lock, you cannot acquire **any** lock anymore, even for a lock on a different database object.

Can't the scheme be relaxed to as long as you release the lock for an object, you cannot acquire the same lock again? So you release the lock on an object when you won't touch it again?

Is there any anomalies in this way?